# positioning dropdown inside `container-fluid` navigation bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to position my dropdown in front of my sign up button and navbar, however, when I open the dropdown, it expands the navbar. I do not want this, I want the dropdown to overlap the navbar. It also offsets my sign up button. I have listen the code for my navbar below, as well as a picture of what it looks like.

[screenshot With dropdown open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJsDO.jpg)

[screenshot with dropdown closed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCI4U.jpg)

basically I'm trying to get the dropdown to open without expanding the navigation bar.

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid justify-content-between">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#leftMainNav" aria-controls="leftMainNav" aria-label="Toggle left navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                <img src="assets/images/logo-l.png" class="img-fluid" alt="CBS Logo">
                CherryBerry <span class="text-red"> Studios </span>
              </a>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-menu" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#signupModal">Sign Up</button>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#rightMainNav" aria-controls="rightMainNav" aria-label="Toggle right navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="rightMainNav" aria-labelledby="rightMainNav">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <h5 class="offcanvas-title p-0 m-0 justify-content-middle" id="rightMainNavLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white justify-content-end" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body justify-content-end">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="leftMainNav" aria-labelledby="leftMainNav">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
          <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="leftMainNavLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
          <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: You can use position property in your dropdown-menu class so it will not take space in header.

Comment: what position property? there are multiple position properties.

Comment: I have posted one answer for reference but you need to do changes according to your requirement.

Comment: @BhartiSharma where is your answer? i do not see where it would be.

Comment: Maybe you need to refresh your page but I am posting here as well.

Comment: .nav-item.dropdown {position: relative;}
.dropdown-menu {position: absolute;top: 20px;left: 0;width: 200px;}

Comment: Make sure this is just a reference and you need to update CSS property of top, left and width pixels in dropdown-menu element according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update this position property according to your requirement. However you can check below example :-

```
.nav-item.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if im doing something wrong, but this code does not seem to work. I have applied different position properties, but the dropdown does still seem to expand the navigation bar,

Comment: Okay. So did you try to check if this css is visible in your browser inspect by selecting element in browser @Lil_PhyziX ?

Comment: I cannot see the styles when i click on the element, however if i go to network then check the CSS file edge does indeed pick up the styles. @Bharti Sharma

Comment: It means the css is not actually functioning in your browser for this elements. Can you try to add this CSS inline in corresponding elements in your html. check if it's visible or not ?

Comment: Nothing happened, however when i increase the pixels on the width property it does pick it up, because i increased it to 2000px and it did in deed make the dropdown take up the entire screen width. @Bharti Sharma.

Comment: ```<li class="nav-item dropdown" style="position: relative;">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 0; width: 200px;">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li> <hr class="dropdown-divider"> </li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li> </ul></li>```

Comment: You added inline css like above right ?

Comment: Can you edit your question with running Code Snippet ?

Comment: Yes. But i dont know how to

Comment: There is a square code box on your editor, if you click on it then you can add HTML, CSS and javascript in it and if you are unable to find it then just press Ctrl-M in your editor.